# Shopping Cart Price Rule that excludes products on discount code

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules

Do we have any configuration in Magento where we can set that if already a discount promotion rule is applied on a product,

2nd promotion rule should not be applied to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can Stop Further Rules Processing

[image]

Set Priority of Rules as well

Comment: Stop further Processing to 1st rule or 2nd..? and what does it do..?

Comment: if Stop Further Rules Processing is yes then no any other rules will be apply on cart

Comment: if your 1st rules is applied and is Stop further Processing then it will not check for 2nd rules